# Reading every other line in python file

Tags: python

I want to skip a line and read next line.

```
#from __future__ import print_function
with open ('t1.txt','r') as f1:
    for i in f1:
        s2 = next(i)
        s1 = i
        print(s1 + '\n' + s2)
        f1 = next(f1)
```

Here is file `t1.txt`

```
1,2
3,4
10,11
12,13
20,21
22,23
30,31
32,33
40,41
42,43
50,51
52,53
```

I am trying to read 1st and 2nd line, then increment file iterator to skip a line, and read next  line. But getting error as `TypeError: str object is not an iterator`. How can I do this? (Using python 2.x and 3.x, if it matters)

Comment: You wrote `s2 = next(i)`, where `i` is a string. Change that to say `s2 = next(f1)`. Then, change `f1 = next(f1)` to just `next(f1)`; otherwise, you are assigning the skipped line to `f1`.

Comment: @wecsam `f1` is file iterator, so `next(f1)` should be file iterator too. So if I write `f1 = next(f1)`, how does `f1` get a string? This is the part I am confused.

Comment: s1=i s2=next(f1) after that you would need to keep a count to determine if you needed the extra next(f1). It depends whether you need to keep skipping every third line or not. You don't specify in you question.

Comment: @wde234 Look at the documentation for the `next()` method (https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next). It says: "Retrieve the next item from the iterator." The return value for `next()` is not the iterator; rather, it is the next item inside the iterable. In this case, the items are strings.